# How are copper busbars connected to each other?

Tags: copper, busbar

How are busbars connected to each other? A quick google image search makes it obvious that it is bolts.

https://i.ibb.co/8D05Sk5/power-dist-jpg.jpeg

The specifics of the bolts is what I am most interested in:

1. What material are the bolts made of? It looks to be stainless which is odd since stainless has higher resistance. This makes me conclude that bolts are not meant to carry current, and are really only for holding the two busbars together. Copper would be the best case as it would expand allong with the buss bars but copper is soft so it might loosen faster. Do you know of a code requirement for what material busbar bolts should be?
2. Stack layout? - What would be the stacking look like? `BOLT-> WASHER (what kind?) -> Copper1 -> Copper2 -> Washer(what kind?) - Nut (what kind?) -> Double nut?`. I’m reading to use a Belleville washer. Again is there a code requirement in your country for this?
3. Torque specifications? - I believe that torque specification should be at the recommended rating depending on the material of bolt. I also believe that bolt size will depend on the busbar size, but there could be code requirement of how much force copper be squished together. (Do you know of any in your country?)

A bit of disclaimer I’m not trying to build anything.  I am really just curious to how it is done.

Comment: I did a conductance test on different fastener materials a couple years ago to pique my curiosity.  Bought #6-32 machine screws 2 inches long in three different materials and measured resistance with milliohm meter from end to end.  Got three of each type and averaged the results.  Brass (weight=3.06g) was 1.20mΩ.  18-8 stainless-steel (weight=3.00g) was 7.30mΩ.  Zinc electroplated carbon steel (weight=2.91g) was 1.89mΩ.  I also took the zinc plated one and left it in an overnight bath of vinegar to eat away the zinc plating and it still measured the same exact resistance after that.

Comment: Anyway, my takeaway from that is that even though the stainless was relatively much higher than the others, it was still a small number and usually you're only using a tiny portion of the fastener at the joints.  How well the bonding is, is probably what makes a bigger difference than the material itself.

Comment: Something to also bear in mind is that when you drill a hole in a busbar you are also reducing the current carrying area of the bar in that region

Answer (score 5):

**(1)**

For bolt-material, i found this table. However, it seems to be incomplete.

[image]

[Table 20, Page 96](https://p537794.webspaceconfig.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Copper-for-Busbars.pdf)

**(2)**

Regarding bolting, i found these explanations:

[image]

[Figure 60/61, Page 90](https://p537794.webspaceconfig.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Copper-for-Busbars.pdf)

[image]

[Figure 70/71, Page 98](https://p537794.webspaceconfig.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Copper-for-Busbars.pdf)

**(3)**

Regarding torque, i found this information:

[image]

[Table 22, Page 99](https://p537794.webspaceconfig.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Copper-for-Busbars.pdf)

You can derive your torque from this graph:

[image]

[Figure 69, Page 95](https://p537794.webspaceconfig.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Copper-for-Busbars.pdf)

Comment: The AppNote lists many possibilities for bolt material. In a non-corrosive environment, I would use high strength steel. Copper bolts seem inviting, but the first time a technician who works on cars on the weekend touches it, they will shear the bolts.

Comment: @Mattman944 the ones I've seen have looked like stainless. Brass would be better than steel for conductivity, and better than copper for strength.

Comment: @ChrisH Conductivity isn't relevant, since the face-to-face contact area of a join is going to be much larger than the normal heightXthickness area of the busbar runs.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I agree that ought to be the case, but it was in response to "copper bolts seem inviting" in the previous comment.

Comment: @ChrisH granted, but the bottom line is that the most important property of a bolt is that it doesn't let up on the contact pressure. In fact I'm tempted to say that "bolts must be good conductors" is the same type of fallacy as "bolts must be good locating dowels".

Comment: ElectronicsStudent - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However your answer is getting flags from other site members as it is not currently a valid *answer* on Stack Exchange. It totally relies on that linked document - if the link dies, then your answer becomes useless, as no-one would then be able to see what "Figure 60/61/70" and "Table 22/Figure 69" are. Please consider improving the answer to make it "stand alone".

Comment: (continued) You can see more details of what we expect regarding links in answers [here](/help/how-to-answer) e.g. "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Also see [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) of why link-only answers are not considered valid *answers*. TY

Comment: @SamGibson Changed my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some example excerpts from Siemens product data for [switchboards](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:c2069abf-2080-49ff-b1ad-6bbd316d56a1/sie-selection-and-application-guide-dist-switchboards.pdf)  and [circuit breakers](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/215/21463215/att_863271/v2/3WL3_operating_manual_NAFTA_UL1066_engl_2015_201512101417115285.pdf).

I didn't check other manufacturers, but I recall [Belleville washers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belleville_washer) to be standard in bolted joints. I suspect there is some variation in the fastener dimensions and torque, depending on ratings and application, but this gives an idea.

Siemens uses a Belleville washer on each side of the joint and 1/2" SAE Grade 5 Carbon Steel Bolts, with a torque of 50 ft-lbs:

[image: Splice Plates]

> All splice plates can be accessed, bolted
> and unbolted from the front of the
> switchboard to make connections of
> adjacent sections easy. **Each splice plate
> is attached with a 1/2 inch bolt and a
> 2-inch or 3-inch belville washer on each
> end. This reduces installation time while
> increasing contact pressure at the joint.**
> To make installation and servicing of the
> splice plates easier, all phase and neutral
> through-busses are stacked one above
> the other.

[image: Detail]

> Securing line and load-side busbars
> Use grade 5 bolts 1/2" and Belleville washers. Tighten to a torque of 70 Nm / 50 lb-ft.

In the US, these details of manufacture aren't generally covered by the Electrical Code (Usually NEC or some variation).  Instead, the Codes require equipment to be listed, and the listing agency (e.g. UL) will apply a standard (e.g. [UL 891](https://www.shopulstandards.com/ProductDetail.aspx?UniqueKey=36091)).

Answer (score 3):

When bolting bars together is not an option or not preferred (for example, when combining busbars in a corner), flexibar can be used. Yes, you can bend anything up to 10x100mm. No, you don't want to if you don't have to.

Examples (no affiliation) are [Eriflex advanced](https://www.nvent.com/en-us/eriflex/products/nvent-eriflex-flexibar-advanced-tinned-copper-0) using tinned copper and [Cu-flex](https://www.cubic.eu/download-cu-flex/) using woven copper.

This allows you to put the connections in all kind of shapes:
[image: Example flexibar]

[image: Example flexibar not-connected]

[image: Example cu-flex]

Multiple types of clamps exist, usually from the same manufacturer as the rest of the flexibar. As for technical details as torque, to make sure you're using rated material you'd have to follow the manufacturer's specification.

[image: Flexibar clamps]

[image: On ACB flags]